# How to check / change NVME HMB on Linux?

Tags: linux, ssd, nvme

New DRAM-less NVME SSDs use a portion of the system memory as HMB (Host memory buffer).

How can I check / change NVME HMB on Linux?
(to verify it is working correctly or alter its behavior)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the NVMe base specification 2.0a](https://nvmexpress.org/wp-content/uploads/NVMe-NVM-Express-2.0a-2021.07.26-Ratified.pdf), the NVME feature ID for the Host Memory Buffer is 0x0d. You can check it with the `nvme get-feature` command:

```
# nvme get-feature /dev/nvme0 -H -f 0x0d
get-feature:0xd (Host Memory Buffer), Current value:0x000001
        Memory Return       (MR): False
        Enable Host Memory (EHM): Enabled
        Host Memory Descriptor List Entry Count (HMDLEC): 10
        Host Memory Descriptor List Address     (HMDLAU): 0x0
        Host Memory Descriptor List Address     (HMDLAL): 0xffff7000
        Host Memory Buffer Size                  (HSIZE): 9728
```

You can also find some information under `/sys/class/nvme/`, in the directory of the respective NVMe controller.

The `nvme` kernel module also has the `max_host_mem_size_mb` parameter which you can use to limit the maximum HMB size per controller.

Another `nvme` module parameter, `use_cmb_sqes` can be used to forbid the use of controller's memory buffer for I/O SQes. Assuming I've understood this correctly, this could be used to make any NVMe work like a DRAM-less one.

You can find the current values for the module parameters at `/sys/module/nvme/parameters/`, and also change some of them dynamically from there.

Comment: The NVMe base specification says: "Host Memory Buffer Size (HSIZE): This field specifies the size of the host memory buffer allocated in memory page size (CC.MPS) units." The typical basic memory page size in x86 hardware is 4 KiB, so you'll have to multiply the HSIZE by 4096 to get the HMB size in bytes.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you configure max_host_mem_size_mb to force the SSD to take up much more host memory? Could one increase this to the size of a typical DRAM on high end drives to emulate the performance on an HMB enabled drive? Has anyone tried this?